# How to make part tab inactive (disable) in Eclipse RCP?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, desktop-application, e4

I have partStack with a lot of parts in tabs. I'd like to know how can I make tabs inactive when I don't need them and active when I need.

By inactive I mean tab which is visible but I can't click on it and it is like disable function (for example text on it is gray instead of black).

I use an e4 RCP (with Application.e4xmi).

Thanks for help.

Comment: Is this an e4 RCP (using an Application.e4xmi) or a 3.x compatibility RCP?

Comment: I use e4 RCP (updated in question).

Answer (score 0):

Handling of the selection of parts in a part stack is handled by the part stack renderer `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer` which basically uses a `CTabFolder`.

You can use a renderer factory to override the stack renderer [see here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4Renderer/article.html)

You can extend the existing `StackRenderer` class and override methods to change its behavior. In this case probably the `hookControllerLogic` method. But you are going to have to study the source carefully to see what needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using using *EPartService* to manipulate a part but I think active/inactive part just means visible or not.

Or you can just loop and disable all swt controls yourself manually

Answer (score 0):

Use Renderer factory to override the stack renderer.
Extend the existing StackRenderer class and override hookControllerLogic() or activate() methods with empty implementation.

Example-

```
public class MyE4Part extends ContributedPartRenderer {

/*
 * Don't activate the Part on part selection. part should not be gain the focus on any
 * selection on part .
 */

@Override
public void hookControllerLogic( MUIElement me )
{
    //Don't do anything.
    //super.hookControllerLogic( me );
}
```

}